# MVC get a person name and place it into a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to get a persons who's logged in to the system and place his name into a textbox. How would i do this?. This is how my view looks like

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

Now how do I get a user who is logged in from the controller and place his name inside this textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this in view:

```
@Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

using textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="Username" value="@Membership.GetUser().UserName"/>
```

May be you need to include **namespace** on top of **View** as well but not sure about it:

```
@{
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
}
```

Comment: That works but one question, @ahmed ilyas said its bad use of MVC if you calling things directly from the view. So whatever you've suggested is it efficient?

Comment: it is if you do big operations and data access layer work in view oherwise in your scenario there will be no issue in it

Comment: IMHO: As soon as you do data manipulation (e.g. changing the username) you should use a model, but just to display the username a model is overkill IMO => as you seem to do editing here I would recommend a model...

Answer (score 0):

The current user is stored in the `User` property, which should be availalbe in controller and view. You can instert that into a textbox via e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <lable class = "control-label col-md-2">TEXT</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="@User.Identity.Name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use it "via a model" you need to create a model in the controller and assign it there:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the controller something like:

```
return View(new UserModel { Name = User.Identity.Name });
```

Comment: the model should always have the properties of which you are going to  be displaying data, not in the View. The controller would set those values in the model or if you are going for a fat model thin controller approach, the model would be the one to set its own property for the username in this case, the view should only ever (strictest way possible) just display/bind the value from the model

Comment: True for a "edit field" like asked here, but for e.g. "Hello NAME" printings in the header IMO it is the better way to use `@User.Identity.Name` directly in the view.

Comment: I agree to disagree :)

Comment: You would add the username to EVERY model, just to forward it EVERY time to e.g. "_LoginPartial" instead of simply using `@User.Identity.Name` in the partial view? Sound extremly painfull and hard to maintain to me...

Comment: not at all. you only store what you need to display to the view or when posting and validation fails, then the values are still in the model and to be displayed again. Nothing wrong with that at all. your model should always contain the data you are going to display or edit. Simple. That is how models should work and is recommended by Microsoft otherwise half your info is in the view and half is in the model. so now you have 2 places to maintain which is painful.

Comment: Actually MS does use it the same way I suggested in their default MVC template - inside their `_LoginPartial.cshtml` they have a `"Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!"`. Maybe we are talking around each other: As soon as you edit ANY data you definitely should use a model, but to display e.g. the username in the header of every page it is not the case IMO.

Comment: It's a sample template and not a fully complete end to end

Comment: Don't agree. Sorry mate :) Difference between starter and common practice and best practice.

Comment: I think we really need to agree to disagree, but you are wrong with saying `so now you have 2 places to maintain which is painful.` in this case. If you add the username you show on EVERY page to EVERY model (as this is what you would need to do according to your logic) you need to maintain EVERY model instead of just the one partial view, where you directly use `@User.Identity.Name`...

Comment: in which case if there are common things being put across the site, you use the 1 model and 1 partial view - simple.

Comment: And you need to supply this model to EVERY view and e.g. add it as a "sub-model" to every other model you need on your page. IN THIS CASE (and VERY FEW other) I see no benefit, but just problems/maintainability issues doing "everithing with a model".

Comment: this is where inheritance comes in play. I think you are misunderstanding something here :)

Comment: No - if I force the inheritance of one base model I may have problems elsewhere if I want/need to inhert something else as C# does not support multiple inheritance. I use inherited models very ofter, but not for such cases. I created a new question in the code-review section to maybe get input from others: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48157/mvc-use-model-for-everything

Comment: Or now here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/237015/use-model-for-everything-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Your model should look like:

```
public class MyModel
{
   string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller you should have something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = new MyModel{ Name = User.Identity.Name };
   return View(model);
}
```

Your view should have `@model MyModel` on top of it.
After that you should be able to display the users name.

Answer (score -1):

Before doing any of the suggestion provided. ensure that your site configured for windows authentication

Comment: You can still use User.Identity.Name with Forms Authentication, Windows Auth isn't required.